# How to filter query with empty dummy column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have situation where **must** compare empty dummy field in **like**.

```
SELECT id, name, contact, landline, '' fax
FROM table1 
WHERE contact LIKE '%123%'
   OR landline LIKE '%123%'
   OR fax LIKE '%123%'
```

After execution it gives error like:

> Unknown column 'fax' in 'where clause'

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible; you cannot use aliases defined in the same `SELECT` in the `WHERE`.

MySQL extends the use of the `HAVING` clause, so you can move the conditions to `HAVING`:

```
SELECT id, name, contact, landline, '' as fax
FROM table1
HAVING contact LIKE '%123%' OR landline LIKE '%123%' OR fax LIKE '%123%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the original query up in a derived table (sub-query). Apply the conditions on its result:

```
select id, name, contact, landline, fax
from
(
    SELECT id, name, contact, landline, '' fax
    FROM table1 
) dt
WHERE contact LIKE '%123%'
   OR landline LIKE '%123%'
   OR fax LIKE '%123%'
```

ANSI SQL compliant solution, will work with most dbms products.